# How can i get the context of the MUI theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is how you create a theme and propagate it using MUI.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";

const myTheme = createTheme({
  backgroundColor: {
    primary: "#f9f9fb",
    secondary: "#ededf3",
    tertiary: "#cbcbdc",
  },
})

const Index: FC = () => {
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
       <App />
   </ThemeProvider>
};
```

Now, for some reason, I need to get the context of the MUI theme in my app.

I've search everywhere but it seems that they do not expose the context anywhere. I found 3 contexts in `private-theming`, `styled-engine` and `styled-engine-sc` but none of them worked.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5):

The way you create the theme it wrong should be like following:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: red[500],
    },
  },
});
```

with the property palette.

and the way to get values  you could use the hook `useTheme` .

first import

```
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material";
```

and inside your components you can use the palette you set to your theme like:

```
const { palette } = useTheme();
```

Answer (score 0):

MUI uses the context provided by the styled engine:

```
import { ThemeContext } from '@mui/styled-engine';
```

It can also be imported directly from your engine of choice (`emotion` in the example below):

```
import { ThemeContext } from '@emotion/react';
```